# Reddit API: POST /api/search_reddit_names

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, get, reddit

I'm trying to do a simple autofill for a subreddit searchbar.

Here is my jQuery code when I attempt to use the provided [GET search](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_search) option:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.reddit.com/reddits/search.json?q=%27+'+query+'+%27&limit='+AUTOFILL_LIMIT, function(data){

    var results = data.data.children;

    console.log('Query: "'+query+'"');
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
    {
        console.log('  '+results[i].data.display_name);
    }
});
```

Here is my jQuery code when I attempt to use the provided [POST search](https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#POST_api_search_reddit_names) option:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.reddit.com/api/subreddits_by_topic?query=%27+'+query+'+%27', function(data){

    var results = data.data.children;

    console.log('Query: "'+query+'"');
    for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
    {
        console.log(results[i].data.display_name);
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? I keep getting an `{error: 404}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url is incorrect. It should be `http://api.reddit.com/api/subreddits_by_topic.json?query=`

Also, if you're using the POST search option (which that URL is not, by the way) then `getJSON` won't work, as it's using a GET request method. You'll have to use `$.post` or `$.ajax` (which I recommend), if you're using jQuery.